# How do i save a record when it violates foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, webforms

I have three tables, `player`, `player points` and `team`. I have a foreign key set to team and player points but when I try to insert into the player table I get the following error.

```
try
{
   string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

   if (id != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
   {
       _playerId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);
   }

   string teamIds = Request.QueryString["teamId"];

   if (teamIds != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
   {
       _teamId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);
   }

   player _player = new player();
   _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(_playerId);
   _player.Name = txtFullName.Text;
   _player.email = txtEmail.Text;
   _player.address = txtAddress.Text;
   _player.description = txtDescription.InnerText;
   _player.gender = dlGenders.SelectedValue.ToString();
   _player.regEmailSent = chksendActivationEmail.Checked;
   _player.modifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
   _player.teamId = new Guid(ddlTeam.SelectedValue.ToString());

   player_points _points = new player_points();

   if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfBirth.Text) == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
       _player.dob = Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfBirth.Text);

   if (_player.player_id == null)
       _player.player_id = _dal.genPlayerID(new Guid("B9B2A89A-2295-4E48-BBA4-9DC28A1855FB"), new Guid("6E424913-A9A4-4A46-9785-C8AFA09C82DB"));

   if (_teamId != Guid.Empty)
   {
        _player.teamId = _teamId;
   }

   if (id == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
   {
        _dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
   }

   _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

My question is: how do I get the id value from the save to be able to link my player points table for the error I am getting is:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_player_points\". The conflict occurred in database \"DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37\", table \"dbo.player_points\", column 'id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Obviously I need to no the player Id number which is a guid filled in using `newid()` on the SQL Server side before I can add to the player points table.

This screenshot shows my player table:

[image]

And this one shows my player points table:

[image]

The foreign key is based on player id so I presume I have to have a record in player points for the save to work but how do i get the player id when I have not saved id grrr stressed much

Now a player can have many player points values so is this the right way i have it setup

**Here is my edmx to show my entites as describe by marcs**
[image]

When I try marc s method i dont have an add option for some reason why is that ?.

[image]

The solution by marc wont work as I appear not to have and add function on my player points.

Comment: If you're using **Entity Framework**, you can simply assign the `_points` to the `_player`'s navigation property to the `player_point` table, and then just save the player (including this points) in a single call - EF will handle all the fixing up of the ID's that need ot be inserted.....

Comment: @marc_s can u please provide an answer i am using ef5 and web forms and a code example please ill mark it as an answer ?? with the refernces in place i will mark as the answer so i will, so i persume with this approach i need to have at least one entry in player points per user what if i dont want any until the user has inserted it themselfs from front end can you explain both ways please.

Comment: Unfortunately no - you haven't showed us what your entities look like.....

Comment: @marc_s one sec ill upload my edmx

Comment: @narc_s please see update i have added the edmx

Answer (score 2):

Basically - don't mess with this - just let EF handle all the details!

You just create your player

```
player _player = new player();
// ... set all the _player properties
```

and then your player points:

```
player_points _points = new player_points();
// set the properties of _points as needed
```

and then you assign the `_points` to the `_player` into its navigation property (which I don't know what it's called - you didn't show us):

```
// this navigation property might be called something else! Adapt as needed!
_player.player_points.Add(_points);
```

and then you save the two, linked new objects in a single call and let EF do its magic:

```
_dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
_dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
```

and done! EF will insert both entities, and it will fix up the relationship between the entry into the `player_points` and `player` tables - all without you intervening at all. Don't make your developer life too hard! Use the magic of EF!

**Update:** I still don't know what datatype `player_points` in your `player` class is ..... I was assuming it would be a **collection** of multiple values (therefore I used the `.Add()` method) whereby a single player could have multiple player points.

If that's **NOT** the case - if those two entities are linked in a 1:1 fashion (one player only ever has one player_points), then you'd have to use this code instead:

```
_player.player_points = _points;
```

(instead of the call with the `.Add()` method) and then proceed to the end

Comment: please see the edmx screen shot for the navigation property player points how do i  pass the player id though is handled automticcally also i dont see add their when i refresnece the player_points navigation proproperty why is that ?.

Comment: any idea hy i dont have the .add option ?

Comment: @kymberly: not sure - is it a 1:n relationship, e.g. can one player have multiple player_points? Is `player_points` an `ICollection<T>` or what else is it? You should **really** post the code - not just screenshots!

Comment: hi yes that is I HAVE posted code ! on how I added to my entity whattheother code do you want !  the whole edmx file

Comment: please advise me what other code is required and ill post it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck this is how I had to add my foreign key on the actual points table and not the player table I no school boy error but thanks to all for helping.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[player_points](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_player_points_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [playerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [playerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [teamId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [points] [int] NULL,
    [pointsToRedeem] [int] NULL,
    [dateToBeAwarded] [date] NULL,
    [approvedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [approved] [bit] NULL,
    [approvedDate] [date] NULL,
    [siteId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [sentApproveEmail] [bit] NULL,
    [isActivated] [bit] NULL,
    [authUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [authCreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [playerNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [isProcessed] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToAdmin] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToUser] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_player_points] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player_points]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PlayerPoints] FOREIGN KEY([playerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[player] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player_points] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PlayerPoints]
GO
```